# How to search for links in a given page with Bash, or Python or any other popular scripts

Tags: python, shell, search

Given a http/https page, I would like to search for some links on that page, anyone knows how to achieve this goal with Bash, Python or any other popular script languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in python. It will print all tags with a link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
print(soup(requests.get('Your link').content).find_all('a', href=True'))
```

Comment: so is it part of Python standard library?

Comment: No, it isn't. You will have to install them with `pip install requests` and `pip install bs4`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Beautiful Soup. It's an html parser library in python. You'll look for `<a>` tags and grab the inner content.